# Getting total length of an index in each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I want to get an unknown (*changing*) # of rows from a table, between the 1st cell and the last 3. I'm using jQuery's each and don't know why $(this).length doesn't give the total length of the index.

jQuery:

```
$("#parent table:first tr").each(function(i){
    var  goodlng =  $(this).parent().children("tr").length -1;   //this works
    var badlng = $(this).length -1;                        //this doesn't! (always == -1)
});
```

Is the `goodlng` good practice? it seems like a hack to have to go to parent and then back to children.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/W9g6e/) (have console.log()) open.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>unwanted 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>wanted!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>unwanted2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**tl;dr**: Why doesn't `$(this).length == $(this).parent().children("tr").length` inside of an each function. and is there another better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says "cells", but it seems like you're trying to get the number of rows.

If you really want it inside the `.each()`, you could use the [`siblings()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method and the [`andSelf()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) method.

```
$(this).siblings().andSelf().length
```

But if the rows aren't changing, why do it repetitively?

Or if they are changing, I'd just use the native `rows` property on the table to get the length.

```
var table = $("#parent table:first");

table.find('tr').each(function() {

    var len = table[0].rows.length;

});
```

Comment: whoops i meant row thanks! i tried `siblings()` before but didn't know about `andSelf()`. Is that better practice? Or does it really not matter?

Comment: @mazlix: I just updated my answer. You can eliminate the overhead of using jQuery by keeping a reference to the `table`, and getting the `length` of its `rows` property. This will be much faster.

Comment: ...I assume there must be some manipulation of the rows taking place, otherwise you'd be better off caching the quantity outside the `.each()`.

Comment: I have clarified that the # of rows are unkown and may change

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this `$(this).parent().children("tr").length` is the correct way of handling things. `this`, in the context above is a reference to the `tr` node itself. `tr`.length = the length of the `tr`. `tr.parent().children("tr")`, on the other hand is a list of the node's siblings, so  `tr.parent().children("tr").length` is the number of siblings.

Answer (score 1):

This is the context of EACH element, not all of them. Therefore, `this` is only ONE `tr` at a time. That is why the length does not have all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The each() function is unaware of the collection of elements that it is working on. It is dealing with a single element at all times. Thats why when you go to the parent and ask for all children you get the right answer.

```
  $(this)
```

simply refers to the current tr element that you are dealing with, not a collection of them.